# how to launch external app from a button with com.lampa.startapp plugin in cordova

Tags: cordova, github, ionic-framework, ionic2, ionic3

I realy need how to open from my app another apk with a specific package name with a button . I mean when user click generate
Another app with package name com.calculator2.yazid will be launched

I realy want to use this plugin https://github.com/lampaa/com.lampa.startapp

Answer (score 3):

I started with the standard Contact page from the Tabs sample project and installed lampaa’s startUp plugin:
ionic plugin add com.lampa.startapp

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { NavController } from 'ionic-angular';
import { Platform } from 'ionic-angular';

export const myConst = {
  blackboardApp: {
    ios: {
      storeUrl: 'itms-apps://itunes.apple.com/nl/app/blackboard-mobile-learn/id376413870?mt=8',
      appId: 'bblearn://'
    },
    android: {
      storeUrl: 'market://details?id=com.blackboard.android',
      appId: 'com.blackboard.android'
    }
  }
}

@Component({
  selector: 'page-contact',
  templateUrl: 'contact.html'
})
export class ContactPage {

  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public plt: Platform) {    
  }

  openBB() {
    if (this.plt.is('android')) {
      let appId = myConst.blackboardApp.android.appId;
      let appStarter = (window as any).startApp.set({ "package": appId });
      appStarter.start(function (msg) {
         console.log('starting BB app: ' + msg);
      }, function (err) {
        console.log('BB app not installed', err);
        window.open(myConst.blackboardApp.android.storeUrl, '_system');
      });
    } else if (this.plt.is('ios')) {
      let appId = myConst.blackboardApp.ios.appId;
      let appStarter = (window as any).startApp.set(appId);
      appStarter.start(function (msg) {
        console.log('starting BB app: ' + msg);
      }, function (err) {
        console.log('BB app not installed', err);
        window.open(myConst.blackboardApp.ios.storeUrl, '_system'
        );
      });
    } else {
      let msg_err = "Platform not supported";
      alert(msg_err);
      console.log(msg_err);
    }
  }
}
```

Hope it helps!
[Source](https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/launch-or-install-third-party-apps-from-with-in-ionic-app/38419/11)

Comment: But please how do i make i button in the home page , when i click on it tha app launche pleaase

Comment: <button ion-button (click)="openBB()">Light</button>